# Replace image for text when object don't have one

Tags: javascript, css, image, angularjs, angularjs-directive

What I'm using now is a directive that given an object checks if it has an image (a property with the url) and then render an `<img>` element, and if not, it renders a `<div>` with some text that fits where it should be an image, better known as a fallback routine.

I have some doubts;

- is this a propper way of doing it?
- there is another way to do the fallback without using an image? (don't want to create an image with a "No Image" sign and set a path to it)
- the directive output could be displayed in different places, so the `div` or the image not always will have the same style. I havn't seen examples where styles are passed as parameters and don't know if that is a good practice.

I'm new to angular, so I'm open to all ideas.

Comment: you could probably use a default placeholder image when no image is there. Other then that I think your approach is fine

Comment: I agree, you did right putting it inside a directive.